# What is `Experience` in chrome Performance tab of devTools?

Tags: performance, google-chrome-devtools

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiboC.png)

I'm a web front-end developer, and I'm measuring performance in the performance tab of chrome devtools to improve performance.

After measuring the performance for about 12 seconds, looking at the summary, a ridiculous time of over 300 seconds was measured with the item 'Experience'.

This item didn't appear until a while ago, but it suddenly appeared in the last week.
What is this, and is it something that cannot be excluded from the measurement target?

I have never modified chrome devtools settings, just measured performance.

I tried to find a setting for this, but couldn't find it, and I couldn't find anything related to it when I Googled it.

Comment: This entry is mislabeled, it shows [layout shifts](https://web.dev/debug-layout-shifts/).